# TYPO3 Mask Elements - Wrong output

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-mask

I am using TYPO3's mask element extension to create a mask element. There I'm using a RTE to enter some text and print it to the screen. The HTML for the mask element looks like this:

```
<f:if condition="{data.tx_mask_text}">{data.tx_mask_text}<br /></f:if>
```

The problem now is that I can add some text here and it also is printed. But the text also includes HTML tags. So if I type in "Hello" as text into the RTE, then the output is `<p>Hello</p>`.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. All you need to do is add some ViewHelper to your variable, which should be printed, in your case:

```
<f:if condition="{data.tx_mask_text}">{data.tx_mask_text -> f:format.html(parseFuncTSPath: 'lib.parseFunc')}<br /></f:if>
```

The ViewHelper removes all the tags from the text. See further information here:

https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Format/Html.html